# Passing a php variable via url in a batch file on local wamp setup

Tags: php, windows-7, cmd

Environment: Windows 7, PHP 5.3.13, Apache 2.2.22 (WAMP)
Working locally
Accessing external web service

I'm attempting to assign a global variable in PHP via URL inside of a batch command prompt to call a web service. See the following batch line:

start /b "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe" -q "C:\wamp\www\test\scripts\apiTest.php?itemID=%1"  > API_Log%dtStamp%.txt

Upon running this bat file with the actual item ID:
C:\wamp\www\test\scripts\apiTest.bat 1234567

I get an Undefined Index error and matching 404 not found. Upon inspecting the HTTP packet I'm noticing the URL has dropped (never received) the itemID I've specified in the execution string. HTTP info:
http://api.service.com/items//items.xml
http://api.service.com/items/(missing identification info here)/items.xml

I can definitely access specific urls with arguments directly from cmd/batch and I've directly typed the variable into the url and executed this process in a browser with no problem.

I suspect sending the api url directly to the php executable WITH an argument is not possible. The id number is not appending correctly or even at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending it like a GET request you should use something like:

```
start /b "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe" -q "C:\wamp\www\test\scripts\apiTest.php %1" > API_Log%dtStamp%.txt
```

and then access that data with the argv variable.

```
echo $argv[1];
```

So running `C:\wamp\www\test\scripts\apiTest.bat 1234567` will echo `1234567`

Also just in case you need it, the command run in `$argv[0]`, I sometimes use this when outputting the syntax of my script. For example:

```
echo "Syntax: {$argv[0]} [username]";
```

Comment: Many thanks Jordan! I slightly modified your batch line a bit (item reference outside of quote instead of inside), but the suggestion for $argv was sound and works great. Much appreciated.